# SPIM vs MARS for RISC

Tags: mips, mars-simulator, qtspim

I know that MARS is missing some macros, relative to QtSpim, and does not allow overloaded macros.
I would like to know from the point of view of a RISC code whether there are any worthy variations between the two, and what these are if they are useful or make it more user friendly.
Thank you

Comment: _"like MIPS for example"_ Do SPIM or MARS even support anything else?

Comment: One difference, IIRC, is that MARS has support for more syscalls than SPIM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any noticeable differences, as the comments mention mars has support for more types of syscalls, but that's about it.